# MailEnable Webmail - messages and folders will not display

Tags: webmail, mailenable

OS is Win2012

Plesk 11.5 panel

ME Pro 7.5

ME diagnostics are green

There have been no configuration changes to the server. It's been running without issue for some time.

Today found that folders will not display in webmail, and therefore no messages are accessible in webmail. This includes the inbox, deleted items, sent items, etc... If I create a new folder, it says it is created successfully, and in fact I can see the directory appear on the file system. But it will not display in the web browser. I've tried with Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

The only branch that displays are the Mailbox-username and the My Files. Selecting the Mailbox-username branch I get the summary in the main pane that lists the number of messages in the inbox, junk e-mail, and deleted items as well as other data. but I am unable to access any of the folders themselves. They are not even listed in the navigation pane.

As far as I can tell, file permissions are correct. I have even run MEINSTALLER to run the verification. And procmon is not showing any access denied errors.
I have tried removing _index.xml from the user root as well as individual folder directories.

No errors are displayed on the page.
Event log does show errors that about not being able to access _activity.blk. However, those are for mailboxes that no longer exist. But other than that, no other errors found.

I'm out of ideas.

thank you,

- michael

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a .Net Framwork update (KB3186539) . The update breaks webmail so that it will not display folders and messages. This affects multiple versions of MailEanble webamil, including the current version.

Here is a ME thread on the topic
http://forum.mailenable.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=41791

At this time, while there are beta updates for ME, if you have an older version or do not wish to upgrade to a beta, the work around is to make a change to web.config.

In the Mail Enable\bin\Netwebmail directory and adding the following between the  and  tags:

```
<caching><cache disableExpiration="true"/></caching>
```

Updating the web.config resolved the issue on our server.